# MySql use wildcard to generate parameter based result

Tags: mysql

for example i have the table **mail**

```
id | wildcard
------------------
1  | %@hotmail.com
```

i can easily check an email with the stored wildcard **mail**

```
Select * From mail where 'abcde@hotmail.com' like wildcard;
```

Now i want to check a list of different mails. e.g. ('bar@hotmail.com', bar@webmail.com, 'foo@hotmail.com'). Of course i can iterate the list and check every single mail, but i look after an solution to check all with one query. Something like (for the example list) where i can see the triggerd wildcard and the checked email itself

```
email | wildcard
----------------
bar@hotmail.com | %@hotmail.com
foo@hotmail.com | %@hotmail.com
```

is this possible?

**Edit**:
To clarify my intention in other words. The example mail table has more than >1000 wildcards. I have an amount of >10000 mail-address. Now i want to fetch all mail-address from this amount which would trigger at least one wildcard. I can do it with many database request (check every mail), but i would prefer to do this with a single database request. My the fact would help: The mails it self are stored in an other table.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

i think you intend to do this

```
SELECT *
FROM mail
WHERE email like '%@hotmail.com'
```

Comment: the wildcard itself is stored in the database. May i could fetch first all wildcards and use them for the mail table ... IN (... , ...) ...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
SET @wildcard = '@hotmail.com';
SET @wildcard2 = 'foo';

SELECT email, @wildcard as wildcard
FROM mail
WHERE email LIKE CONCAT('%', @wildcard);

SELECT email, @wildcard2 as wildcard
FROM mail
WHERE email LIKE CONCAT(@wildcard2, '%');
```

Comment: Usable for single request. But i can not see how this should work if a have a list of mails, also a list of wildcards.